# Drupal 8 Menu Item Title with HTML inside with TWIG

Tags: html, twig, drupal-8

I simply want to wrap part of a menu item title in a strong element:

```
<a href="page">Learn <strong>more</strong></a>
```

But Drupal is escaping the strong element so it appears like this

> Learn <strong>more</strong>

How can I disable the escaping of the html in my twig file? Here is my menu.html.twig :

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, classes) %}
  {% if items %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(menu_level == 0 ? classes : 'dropdown-menu') }}>
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set item_classes = [
          item.is_expanded and item.below ? 'expanded',
          item.is_expanded and menu_level == 0 and item.below ? 'dropdown',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
        ]
      %}

      {% autoescape %}
        {{ link(item.title, item.url)|raw }}
      {% endautoescape %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ _self.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, classes ? classes : ['menu', 'menu--' ~ menu_name|clean_class]) }}
```

EDIT: Updated twig code with my most promising attempt at workaround. Still no love :(

Comment: `{{ link(item.title, item.url) | raw }}` to prevent the `HTML` of escaping

Comment: @Darkbee Great suggestion, but unfortunately, that does work. I think the string is escaped when entering it into Drupal. Now I wish there was a "html_entity_decode" in TWIG.

Comment: U could write an extra filter that does that though

Comment: @DarkBee I actually saw your answer to another question about how to register a new TWIG filter for "html_entity_decode", Im just not sure where to put that in my drupal theme.

Comment: [Here](https://leopathu.com/content/create-custom-twig-filter-drupal-8) is a guide for drupal

Answer (score 2):

Replace `{{ link(item.title, item.url)|raw }}` with

```
<a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.title|raw}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the link title in a variable then pass thaat variable in the twig link function.

```
{% set link_text %}{{ item.title|raw }}{% endset %}
{{ link(link_text, item.url) }}
```

Comment: With this method the link doesn't lose attributes coming from other modules (ie. Menu Link Attributes by yannickoo)